# how i check Line By Line code Deduge or Run (Titanium)?

Tags: titanium, titanium-mobile, titanium-modules

I am new mobile application developer with Titanium. I want to see Line by Line Debug. for check some loop or code. (specially for the "ANDROID")
for Checking where my application is 'Crash'. Please Help Me,

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to set **Toggle Break** point by Right click , Like :

[image]

Then, Right click on your project and select debug as Android Emulator, Like :

[image]

Then Press F5 for line by line debug.

You can also find other options as well.Like:

[image]